# "method is ambiguous for the type" but the types are NOT ambiguous (and the error comes by upgrade from eclipse 3.7.2 to eclipse 4.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I have defined:

```
public static int[] getArray( final int... params ) {
    return params;
}
public static <T> T[] getArray( final T... params ) {
    return params;
}
```

And I use this in

```
getArray( 1, 2 )
```

and now I get in eclipse 4.2 the compile error:

> method is ambiguous for the type

But as you can see this is not ambiguous. What can I do?

Comment: The compiler may be trying to apply autoboxing, in which case it cannot choose any of your methods. I'm not sure, but you might try casting your arguments explicitly: `getArray((int) 1, (int) 2)`

Comment: Please tag with appropriate language (Java ? C# ?).

Comment: By the way javac from the JDK 1.7 agrees with eclipse 4.2

Comment: see this also see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325277/why-does-system-out-printlnnull-give-the-method-printlnchar-is-ambiguo

Answer (score 24):

This was reported as a bug in eclipse [bug 383780](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383780).
Here is the documentation of the fix:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=218320

Basically, to fix the compiler error, get the latest eclipse release([4.2.1](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/) as of now), add the following line after `-vmargs` in `eclipse.ini`: (then you might need to restart eclipse and rebuild you projects)

```
-DtolerateIllegalAmbiguousVarargsInvocation=true
```

That being said, Samuel is correct: the method invocation is ambiguous. The code example above worked before because there was a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383780) in JDK before 1.6; and the custom compiler in eclipse successfully mimicked this bug. When developing Juno, they fixed [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346038) (because the JDK bug was fixed in 1.7) by reporting ambiguous invocation as an error, annoying a lot of people (including me). The fix above asks you to explicitly tell eclipse to "tolerate Illegal Ambiguous Varargs Invocation".

Comment: For the latest eclipse (4.14) and Java 8 it is not working again

Comment: This is not working for me in Eclipse 06/2022 with open-jdk-8u242-b08

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Actually this is ambiguous because [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) in java allows you to call a method that expect an `int` with an `Integer` and vice versa, so `getArray( 1, 2 )` can really be a valid call to any of your methods.

As far as I understand what you are doing, you want to have a utility method to create an Array of whatever. Maybe the simplest thing you can do is rename the method that deals with `int` to `getIntArray()`. Or just use `new int[] {1, 2}` which is very readable if you want an `int` array.

You can find this information in the specification of the language at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/jls3.pdf (In your case, determining the invoked method will go to step 3 of the process described in section 15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature, because you use the arity variable, and at step 3, both of the method calls are valid)

Comment: i dont think that this is clear.
we had the same project-settings that use jdk6-compilance-level to build before the upgrade to eclipse 4.2 (former eclipse 3.7.2) and we had no error on building. 
auto-boxing was already used in former configuration.
why upgrading brings this problem?

Comment: @user1430985 I Added a reference to the specification, which explains the behaviour. If I believe the specification, your project had become dependent from a bug in the previous version of eclipse compiler.