# Determining which method will be executed (Type system)

Tags: java

I have a question concerning Java's Type system.

I have four classes A, B, AStar and BStar. 
AStar extends A and Bstar extends B.

On top of that I have another class that has the following
methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AStar a = new AStar();
    BStar b = new BStar();

    someMethod(a,b);
}   

public static void someMethod(A a,BStar b) {
    System.out.println("first");        
}

public static void someMethod(AStar a,B b) {
    System.out.println("second");
}
```

**The implementation that is executed is the first one.**

From my understanding, Java considers the static types 
of the arguments and chooses the signature that is most
specialized ("fits best") as the signature of the method 
that will be called.

While this rule of thumb works most of the time, it fails
in a few cases with the example above being the 'base case' 
(not involving polymorphism etc.)

I spent a considerable amount of time looking for an explanation
of this behaviour (online as well as in the java books I have
at disposal here), but did not find anything.

**I would be very grateful for an explanation or a link to a resource
that explains this behaviour...**

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Which Java compiler version are you using?

Comment: If you're asking this for educational reasons, fine. But in the real world, this will almost never come up. It's a total design smell.

Comment: With Java 6 or 7, I get a compiler error: "reference to someMethod is ambiguous" (http://ideone.com/CVuN8k)...

Comment: openjdk 6.

Purely educational, yes. I never considered that problem myself until a student of mine asked me yesterday. (I am a section teacher at a German university).

Comment: I get the same error with OpenJDK 6...

Comment: I had changed the settings for this workspace to compliance mode for Java 1.5.
That explains why I did not see the error message.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using java 1.5 or before, you would be able to run the program. it was a noted bug which was later fixed with 1.6 and above.

have a look at this:

["method is ambiguous for the type" but the types are NOT ambiguous (and the error comes by upgrade from eclipse 3.7.2 to eclipse 4.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852923/method-is-ambiguous-for-the-type-but-the-types-are-not-ambigues-and-the-error)