# Eclipse Neon does not compile; ambiguous methods

Tags: java, eclipse, ambiguous, eclipse-mars, eclipse-neon

we want to upgrade from Eclipse Mars to Neon, but our projects do not compile. In Mars, the following code compiles:

```
public class AmbiguousMWE {

    private <T, C extends Collection<T>> void foo(final C c, final Function<T, T> b) {}

    private <T> void foo(final T t, final Function<T, T> f) {}

    private void test() {
        foo(new ArrayList<>(), this::get);
    }

    private Object get(final Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    private Object get() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If however we remove the last get() method, the code does not compile due to the error '*The method foo(ArrayList, Function) is ambiguous for the type AmbiguousMWE*'. You can try to change the order of the methods and you might experience different compiler behaviour.

And on top of that, when upgrading to Eclipse Neon, this error always occurs and there are a lot of source code that does not compile anymore.

So first, I don't know what the second get() method has to do with the error, and second, what can be done to tell Eclipse to still compile our code?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: have you read: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852923/method-is-ambiguous-for-the-type-but-the-types-are-not-ambiguous-and-the-erro) ? thought may help based off of ``*is ambiguous for the type*''